# Combine two condition from two table with OR clause in orchard HQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hql, orchardcms

In orchard cms i want to write a query containing two condition over two different `ContentPartRecord` combined with `OR` clause. one possible way to combine conditions is :

```
var query = _contentManager.HqlQuery()
                           .Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<ProductPartRecord>(), a => a.Eq("Title", "myTitle"))
                           .Where(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>(), a => a.Eq("Price", 1000))
                           .List();
```

but this one combines two condition with `And` clause. i think something like following along with some changes (which would be the answer for this question) could be the case:

```
    var query = _contentManager.HqlQuery()
                           .Join(a => a.ContentPartRecord<ProductPartRecord>())
                           .Join(a => a.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>())
                           .Where(a => a.ContentItem(),
                                a => a.Or(p => p.Eq("ProductPartRecord.Price",
 "1000"), t => t.Eq("TitlePartRecord.Title", "myTitle")))
                           .List();
```

but i couldn't get it working.any body have any suggestion?

Comment: You can use a `||` in your `Where` clause

Comment: @user3153169 e.g:     ;) !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use where clause in HqlQuery you need to pass Alias (as first parameter). Alias means that you will be apply where clause to specific table (class that represent this table). And when you use OR clause that you definitely need to compare columns of the specific table in two parts of OR clause (left and right from the OR clause). And i think this is not possible to do you need a standard way.

But you can use:

```
Action<IAliasFactory> productPartRecordAlias = x => x.ContentPartRecord<ProductPartRecord>().Named("productPartRecord");
Action<IAliasFactory> titlePartRecordAlias = x => x.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>().Named("titlePartRecord");

var query = _contentManager.HqlQuery()
    .Join(productPartRecordAlias)
    .Join(titlePartRecordAlias)
    .Where(a => a.ContentItem(), p => p.Gt("Id", "0 AND (productPartRecord.Price = 1000 OR titlePartRecord.Title = 'myTitle')"));
```